# Unable to download WSO2 Business Process Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

When I Try to download WSO2 Process Server, It redirects me to API Manager.

The link is http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server

Is the WSO2 Process Server deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 `Business Process Server`(BPS) is now deprecated and discontinued. But you can still use it. WSO2 BPS was merged to WSO2 `Enterprise Integrator` a couple of years back as a different runtime. So if you want to use BPS capabilities you can download WSO2 EI from [here](https://wso2.com/enterprise-integrator/6.6.0) and start the Business Process Profile. You can read more about the BPS Profile [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+Business+Processes+).

Comment: Thank you,
Is the Data Services Server and Message Broker merged in the EI?

Comment: @firashai Yes, Dataservices is part of Integrator Profile. The Message Broker is merged into EI and comes as a separate profile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the product is not available now.

You can migrate to EI 6.6.0 if you are using WSO2 BPS 3.6.0 - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Upgrading+from+WSO2+Business+Process+Server

In the latest EI/MI versions do not come with the BPS solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to migrate to Micro-integrator 4.1.0 and use the latest capabilities of the enterprise integration. Micro-integrator is the latest version of the WSO2 ESB platform. However, it does not support BPS capabilities as moving forward, WSO2 will continue to provide only the interprise integration capabilities through the platform and for some of the features such as Message Broker and BPS have been deprecated. For use cases on Message Broker and BPS, you need to integrate with 3rd party products such as Camunda (for BPS) and RabbitMQ (for Message Broker).